# Can i divide view in django like that?

Tags: django, django-views

Can i divide view in django like that? And do i need additional urls in my urls.py?

```
  def profile(request):
         if(option) return view1(request)
         else return  view2(request)
```

Comment: Yes you can do this (it would simply be like calling functions), but what is `option`? And why do this, instead of having one view handle multiple things why not simply have two urls and have two views do these two tasks?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat because i need to call difrent views, by the type of user, and also this views need to handle two difrent large forms, and, because, i hate large functions i want to divide it

Comment: Try using [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/) instead of using multiple functions. You can simply use multiple methods in the class instead of multiple functions this way and you can say that the common logic of the view is present all in one class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this without declaring additional urls.